# Disk inexplicably filled

Tags: linux

I have two linux machines which should be near enough identical clones of each other. One of them has 89% useage of `/dev/sda1`, and the other has 27% useage.

I've tried the rather manual process of `du -h` in the root file system and comparing the two, but there are no substantial discreneable differences. Is there any other way to find out where the missing 20GB are?

Thanks!

Problem solved, there was an issue with an unmounted drive which caused it :)

Answer (score 0):

[ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) will display the size of each directory from an ncurses interface. Probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look the information provided with the command

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sda1
```

Do you see any difference in the block size or anything else?

Comment: Hey. No, the only differences are `Free blocks` (as expected), `Lifetime writes` [one is 45 GB, the other 27 GB], and the problematic machine does not have a `first orphan inode`, where the other one does.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try baobab -disk usage analyzer-, a gui tool which displays disk usage in a clever visualization of nested piecharts.

Comment: No gui access unfortunately. We're using SSH